# Best algorithm for Text Search

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, full-text-search

I have a Set of Objects in java (approx 10M+) , what I want is a Data Structure that I can do a full text Search on TITLE of these objects and results to be sorted in a preferred way.

What I want is Performance, no worry about the memory capacity.

What I have tried of doing now is , Have a HashMap of ArrayLists of these Objects. Whenever a new object is inserted The Title is spit by its Words and the object is added to the corresponding ArrayList for all words in the map.

When a search is required , The search phrase is split by words and accessed all the ArrayLists and the ArrayLists are merged and removed duplicates, and sorted.

but for 1M objects it takes about 1 second. is there a way to increase the performance of this search ?

Comment: You are right that it sounds like you should be able to optimise it.  Exactly how depends on how you implemented it. I would start by looking at your CPU and memory profile.  BTW are you using multiple threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/), or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).  They're perfect for this use case, highly optimised, and offer you a lot of other useful features you're likely to need (like fuzzy matches, index management, sharding, and lots more).

If you're determined to roll your own, the data structure you're describing is pretty much [Google's `HashMultimap`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html).  To optimise this, I think you'll need to look at where the time is being spent.  Querying the `HashMap` should be O(1), so it's likely to be the merging and sorting which are slowing things down. - sorts can be quite slow, depending on the `Comparator` you use.

Bear in mind though that exactly what to tune will depend on statistical properties of your queries - if they generally return only one or two results, making the sort efficient is a waste of time.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for quick answer. I have used Lucene , the problem im having with lucene is it doesn't provide functionalities as " %LIKE% " , does it?. I have searched through documents but couldn't find one

Comment: Sure! https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches  ElasticSearch too: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html